# Spring Boot and Angular: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashSet out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: node.js, angular, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm setting an authentication model with Spring Boot and Angular. When I complete the signup form it shows me this error:

```
Signup failed!
" JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashSet out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashSet out of VALUE_STRING token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@57abbf9f; line: 1, column: 112] (through reference chain: com.steg.authentication.message.request.SignUpForm["role"]) "
```

authRESTAPI:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/api/auth")
  public class AuthRestAPIs {

@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
PasswordEncoder encoder;

@Autowired
JwtProvider jwtProvider;

@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginForm 
loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), 
loginRequest.getPassword()));

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = jwtProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) 
    authentication.getPrincipal();

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
    userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getAuthorities()));
      }
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpForm 
    signUpRequest) {
    if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("Fail -> Username 
            is already taken!"),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("Fail -> Email is 
     already in use!"),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // Creating user's account
    User user = new 
    User(signUpRequest.getNom(),signUpRequest.getPrenom(), 
    signUpRequest.getUsername(), signUpRequest.getEmail(),
            encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

    Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    strRoles.forEach(role -> {
        switch (role) {
        case "admin":
            Role adminRole = 
    roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> 
                      Cause: User Role not find."));
            roles.add(adminRole);

            break;
        default:
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> 
                            Cause: User Role not find."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        }
    });

    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("User registered 
                           successfully!"), HttpStatus.OK);
               }    
     }
```

Angular register.component.ts:

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

      import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
      import { SignUpInfo } from '../auth/signup-info';

      @Component({
      selector: 'app-register',
      templateUrl: './register.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
          })
      export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
      form: any = {};
      signupInfo: SignUpInfo;
      isSignedUp = false;
      isSignUpFailed = false;
      errorMessage = '';

      topics:string[] = ['admin','user'];

      constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

         ngOnInit() { }

         onSubmit() {
          console.log(this.form);


          this.signupInfo = new SignUpInfo(
            this.form.nom,
            this.form.prenom,
            this.form.username,
            this.form.email,
            this.form.password,
            this.form.role
                );

            this.authService.signUp(this.signupInfo).subscribe(
              data => {
           console.log(data);
           this.isSignedUp = true;
           this.isSignUpFailed = false;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
    this.isSignUpFailed = true;
  }
);
}
}
```

Angular signup service:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    import { JwtResponse } from './jwt-response';
    import { AuthLoginInfo } from './login-info';
    import { SignUpInfo } from './signup-info';

    const httpOptions = {
           headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                     })
                  };

    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
                })
    export class AuthService {

    private loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin';
    private signupUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
               }

      attemptAuth(credentials: AuthLoginInfo): Observable <JwtResponse>  
        {
         return this.http.post <JwtResponse> (this.loginUrl, credentials, 
        httpOptions);
         }

        signUp(info: SignUpInfo): Observable <any> {
         return this.http.post <string> (this.signupUrl, info, 
         httpOptions);
          }
          }
```

Comment: It is great that you shared a lot of code; but I think we need more context.  What does "complete the sign up form" mean?  Where do you see the error?  It looks like this is a Java error, unrelated to Angular.  Have you tested your service separately from the UI?  Are you sure it returns valid JSON?

Comment: did you try your API in Postman?

Comment: yes i tried it with Postman and it works

Comment: @JeffryHouser yes i think it's java error but i don t know where the problem is